# Python CGI script only printing partial data

Tags: html, webkit

I have a simple web form that sends the contents of a `div` (an SVG document) to the following Python script. The script takes the SVG data and prints it to the browser. The client then saves it as a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb, urllib

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
try:
    data = urllib.unquote(form.getvalue('output-data'))
    fn = urllib.unquote(form.getvalue('output-fn'))
except AttributeError:
    data = None
    fn = None

print "Content-Type: application/x-gzip"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" + str(fn) 
print "Content-Description: File to download\n"
print data;
```

Here is the form:

```
<form id="form-figure-export-svg" action="assets/src/exportSvg.py" method="POST" style="display:none;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="form-figure-svg-data" name="output-data" style="">
    <input type="text" id="form-figure-svg-fn" name="output-fn" style="">
</form>
```

The problem is that if the form contains a lot of data (around about 450-500 KB — actually 524288 bytes; see update below) then the data that the Python script prints is truncated. This corrupts the SVG output. Chrome and Safari browsers truncate at different points — the latest version of Firefox appears to work okay.

I verified that the data in the form is correct (e.g., `console.log($('#form-figure-svg-data').val())`) before it is submitted to the Python script.

Is there some parameter I need to add to the Python script, to ensure that the complete contents of `data` are printed?

Other things I have tried:

- Replacing the `Content-Type` directive with the MIME type `image/svg+xml`
- Adding the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` directive setting of `binary`
- Using the Python `StringIO` and `gzip` libraries to manually compress the SVG data before printing

**Update**

On inspection of output from Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) this might be due to a limit on the maximum length of an `input` field (524288 bytes). I'm investigating to see if there is a way to remove this limit, or use some other means for sending my data through the form without an artificial limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this issue is related to the maximum length allowed by an `input` div in Chrome and Safari (Webkit browsers). Namely, a limitation of 524288 bytes.

To solve this, I replaced the data field in my form with a `textarea` div, which removes this limitation:

```
<form id="form-figure-export-svg" action="assets/src/exportSvg.py" method="POST" style="display:none;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="form-figure-svg-data" name="output-data" style=""></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="form-figure-svg-fn" name="output-fn" style="">
</form>
```

When I submit this form, there is no longer any client-side limitation on the data sent through the form via Chrome and Safari. I could, however, still implement a web server-based limitation on the allowed size of the form data (for security or other testing purposes).